# How to inactivate parts of html code by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

A JS newbie question:

I would like to inactivate a part of a html code (which I manually would do by `<!-- ... -->`) by Javascript, depending on a numeric variable (which I extract from the file name): If var > 10 do inactivate the code.

EDITED:
If possible only simple Javascript!
A demo html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script> 
   var param = 10;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Paragraph One</p>

<p>Beginning of the part to be removed if param > 10</p>
<a href="mailto:ertwtz@gmail.com">E-Mail</a><br><br>
This is simply something other.
Etc.
Etc.
<p>End of the part to be removed</p>

<p>Paragraph Ten</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better if you shared a code sample, so we can help you better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything you want to remove/hide inside one div with a specific class or id, then add an if condition and hide or remove the required div once the condition is true.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p>Paragraph One</p>
<div id="to_remove">
<p>Beginning of the part to be removed</p>
<a href="mailto:ertwtz@gmail.com">E-Mail</a><br><br>
This is simply something other.
Etc.
Etc.
<p>End of the part to be removed</p>
</div>
<p>Paragraph Ten</p>
  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var param = 11;
   if(param >10) document.getElementById("to_remove").remove();
   //OR if you want to show the div later use this:
   //if(param>10) document.getElementById("to_remove").style.display = 'none';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please show this on my demo now added to my OP?

Comment: it is done, you have only to put all the HTML you want to remove inside one div so it will be easy to find and remove.... you have to  add your JavaScript in the body because you cannot find and element in the DOM if it is not yet created.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I tryed to do this but i didn't know that the js script should be after the html code, not in the head. YOU ARE A SCHATZ! Can somebody mark this as answered? I do not see here if I can give you points ... Thank to the others too.

Comment: like I said if you add the script in the head it is like searching for something not created yet (the body is not created) and if you check the console you will see `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` so you have to include the script after that... PS: the only one who can mark the answer as accepted is you :D

Comment: I have lost my glasses ;-) ... Where is a ANSWERED/ACCEPTED button?

Comment: What a beautiful day today!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the elements from the DOM, e.g. by using [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

```js
document.getElementById('div').removeChild(document.getElementById('p2'));
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <p id="p1">Paragraph one</p>
  <p id="p2">Paragraph two</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Hm ... as a newbie ... (1) My part of the code is not a paragraph, it contains some lines inserting images etc. (2) How to combine this with "if var > 10"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property for the same, add two classes `active` and `inactive` with css `.active{display:block}` and `.inactive{display:none}`.now you can use jquery to add and remove active and inactive classes according to your condition.like in jquery you can write

```
if(var > 10){
 $("div").addClass('inactive');
  }else{
 $("div").removeClass('inactive');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `CSS + jQuery` way of achieving this could be by adding the class `disabled`:

```
if(condition) {
    var element = document.getElementByID('#sample_ID');
    element.addClass("disabled");
}
```

This is assuming that you contain the code to be disabled in the `<div id="sample_ID">`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide it, you can do this by using CSS.
E.g. to hide `<div id="myDiv">Bla</div>` you'd use this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
element.style.display = "none";
```

And if you want to show it again at some point:

```
element.style.display = "block";
```

Live example:

```js
function hideDiv() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  element.style.display = "none";
}

function showDiv() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  element.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  border: solid 1px green
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hideDiv()">Hide</button>
<button onclick="showDiv()">Show</button>
<br/>

<div id="myDiv">Bla</div>
```